# What concerns could a network admin have around PrincipalContext ValidateCredentials?

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-framework-version, application-security

I am writing a WPF C# application which will reside predominately on corporate laptops on a domain behind our firewall and using a combination of `Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` and `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` methods to make sure the user is logged into the network and a user within my application.  Everything is working beautifully, including throwing up an additional login box if the user is using a non-domain machine through VPN (a valid condition for some of our users).

I did a little research and cannot determine exactly what the `ValidateCredentials` method actually **does** within AD.  Specifically I want to be able to anticipate any issues my network admins might have, including any strange traffic going over the wire or odd-looking (to them) requests hitting AD.

Has anyone ever received any feedback or observed any strange traffic or activity using this that might make a network admin suspicious?  From all I read, there shouldn't be, but I want to be proactive in case there is.

Comment: I use `PrincipalContext` all the time and the only thing that I am aware of that would cause one to question is issue around someone trying to access the domain from outside the `DMZ` but in theory the validation should fail anyway since they are not on the domain. and you could also write some small code that works along side of the PrincipalContext stuff.. then call the username password validation check that you would normally do via AD to validate username Password I have done this successfully several times. you should be ok using PrincipalContext

Comment: @MethodMan - thanks for that confirmation.  I'll keep moving forward with doing it this way.